How to optimize the below Pyspark code while inserting data into Lake database table in azure synapse
The below code we running the job incrementally every 10 mins in Azure Synapse pipeline(inserting 3k to 4k records for every run) taking more time to insert the records into the table. we are not able to perform partition on the table. how we can insert the records in lessthan 5 mins to target table.
spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.optimizeWrite.enabled", "true")
spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.autoCompact.enabled", "true")
 
numberof_partitions = 10  
col_data = employeedata.coalesce(numberof_partitions)
 
col_data.write .format("delta") .mode("append").saveAsTable(f"`{database_name}`.`{table_name}`")
 
spark.sql(f"OPTIMIZE {database_name}.{table_name}")

Cluster configuration:
Small (4 vCores / 32 GB) - 3 to 5 nodes
Allocated vCores 12
Allocated memory 96GB

I have tried the below approach:
df = df.repartition("department", "date")
df.write.format("delta").mode("append").partitionBy("department", "date").saveAsTable("default.employee")

I have created four columns: id, name, department, and date.
Next i did partitioned the data by department and date using the repartition method.
write the data to a Delta Lake table named employee in the default database, partitioned by department and date.
In your case use the approriate column for partition
Results:
time_taken = end_time - start_time
print("Time taken to insert records: {:.2f} seconds".format(time_taken))

Time taken to insert records: 48.13 seconds

